# The integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+ax^{-\alpha}}(\exp(-\frac{[x+c]^{2}}{2b}))dx$

Tags: integration, approximation

Everyone. I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over 1 + a\,x^{-\alpha}}\,
\exp\left(-\,{\left[\,x + c\,\right]^{2} \over 2b}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\quad 
\mbox{where}\quad a, b, c, \alpha > 0.
$$
This integral comes from one problem related to stochastic geometry.

And I've tried $\texttt{Mathematica}$ and $\texttt{Matlab}$, and none of them are able to give the symbolic results, which make me think it is impossible to obtain the results directly. Therefore, my purpose to ask the question is to know whether there exists any kind of approximations of the integral or not or some tricks to solve the integral. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if you Taylor expand the first factor ? The integral will always be convergent due to the Gaussian factor...

Comment: @AlexandreKrajenbrink, Thank you for your feedback. I have one question, what you mean about the Taylor expansion is $\frac{x}{1+ax^{-\alpha}}=\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{a+x^{\alpha}}=\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{a}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{\sqrt[\alpha]{a}})^{\alpha}}\stackrel{(\text{Taylor Expansion})}{=}\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{a}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\frac{x}{\sqrt[\alpha]{a}})^{n}$ or any other taylor expansion? Because the aforementioned requires $\frac{x}{\sqrt[\alpha]{a}}<1$ to be coveragent, which may be impossible when $x$ increases to infinity. Are you meaning other expansions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you can use the Laplace approximation for this integral:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method

$\frac{x}{a + x^{-\alpha}}\exp(-\frac{[x+c]^{2}}{2b}) = \exp(\ln(\frac{x}{a + x^{-\alpha}})-\frac{[x+c]^{2}}{2b})$

Now for the Laplace approximation, consider the function $f(x) = \ln(\frac{x}{a + x^{-\alpha}})-\frac{[x+c]^{2}}{2b}$

Comment: thank you for your comment, and I have browsed the website which is very helpful for me to solve the problem. One quick question, how do you deal with the first part of the integral, i.e., $\frac{x}{1+ax^{-\alpha}}$, Taylor expansion to transform it to be other equivalent expression expressed like exponential function and then use the Laplace approximation?

Comment: You can just use the fact that $f(x) = e^{log(f(x))}$ if $f(x) > 0 \forall x$. Since your integral is from $0$ to $\infty$ then $f > 0$

Comment: Yes, I've tried $f(x)=e^{\log(f(x))}$, and it is a bit hard to find the optimal value $x$ to maximize $f(x)$. But, the Laplace approximation really inspires me, thank you, Richard.

Comment: Have you tried the optim function from R (the free statistical software) ? Is very easy to find the maximum of that function using it.

Comment: No, I did not. I will try it out. Thank you for letting me know that, and I appreciate your help.